# If I report a bug, will my achievements be canceled by the moderator?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bug-reports

As the title of my question states, if I report a bug that affects my achievements (reputation/badge/privileges/etc.), will my achievements be canceled/undone by the moderator?

This can happen in two cases:

- The bug causes the achievement to be earned.
- The bug reverted the loss of an achievement.

I'm asking for curiosity only.

Comment: +1 for original (and brave ;)) question. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard +1 for your compliment :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, yes. If you unintentionally yet all the same illegitimately earned anything through a bug, it will generally be retracted as part of this fix. This has been done with erroneous badges and reputation alike - and it tends to be done to everyone who is affected by it, not just the reporter.

Comment: iam not understanding his question, please can you elabrate it?

Comment: Also... If you knowingly exploit a bug and it's detected because of a pattern of behaviour, the consequences are likely to be worse than losing a badge :)

Comment: @Damodar: The question is essentially, if for example, you found a bug that let you vote for yourself, and reported it, would the rep / badges from those votes cast by you, for your questions/answers be removed from your total.

Comment: I think the thing that bears emphasizing here (at least the thing that makes it seem more fair to me) is that the erroneous achievements are removed for *everyone*, not just the person who reports the bug.