# What does "bug-reports" tag mean

Tags: support, meta

> This tag is not for reporting a bug! Use this tag for questions
>   *about* bug reports.

Um... Can't understand. 
Why to write question *about* bug reports?
To report bugs in bug reports?

Comment: `[discussion] [bug-report]`, `[feature-request] [bug-report]`, etc..

Comment: We already have `[bug]` for bug reports themselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really. Then why to write *about* bug reports?

Comment: Why *not* write about bug reports? Did you look at the questions tagged as such at all?

Comment: For example "I think that whenever you report a bug you should get a cookie [bug-reports][feature-request]".

Comment: This is what happens when meta goes meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you discuss reporting bugs and your post itself is *not* a bug, you use [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports). Like:

- [Does Stack Overflow fix bugs or problems reported on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212164/does-stack-overflow-fix-bugs-or-problems-reported-on-meta)
- [Why don't we get responses from bug reports?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports)
- [If I report a bug, will my achievements be canceled by the moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91919/if-i-report-a-bug-will-my-achievements-be-canceled-by-the-moderator)

These are not bugs, they discuss things *about* reporting bugs.