# Android adds new answer instead of comment

Tags: bug, android-app

After adding a comment, if I want to add another within the grace period for edits, either because it won't fit in the existing comment or is a separate thought which should get treated separately for votes and flags and future deletion, well the Android application takes away my add comment button during the grace period.

[image]

What's worse, the add answer button ends up in the same area of the UI. And then the Android app has no UI that I can find for deleting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23541299/103167) again. Nor does it show the warning about adding a second answer vs editing that is a feature of the desktop site.

Ideally:

- don't hide the add comment button
- add the warning for answers after the first
- put "delete" on the popup menu for my own answer

But the first of these is most critical.

Meta bug report on the Android app (issues found while writing this question)

- give me my insert image button
- add a UI for linking to recently visited questions... Especially when writing a meta question.
- the bug-reports tag needs to die
- after fixing the tags to use bug not bug-reports, the app wrongly hit me with an anti-spam timer (you can't do this, ie hit submit again, for another 37 seconds)

Comment: Here's the answer that was added by mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23541299/103167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.84 beta:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Don't hide the *Add comment* button: you can now comment multiple times on the same post.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Give me my insert image button: see [Allow us to link to an image online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246405/allow-us-to-link-to-an-image-online)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) The [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports) tag needs to die: probably won't happen (see [What does "bug-reports" tag mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230582/what-does-bug-reports-tag-mean)), but should be improved in the future (see [usability roadblocks submitting bug reports in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248495/usability-roadblocks-submitting-bug-reports-in-the-android-app))
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) After fixing the tags to use [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) not [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports), the app wrongly hit me with an anti-spam timer (you can't do this, ie hit submit again, for another 37 seconds): there's a cooldown between API call to prevent abuse, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900)

---

Outstanding:

- Add warning when attempting to post a second answer
- Put *Delete* on the popup menu for my own answer: see [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)
- Add a UI for linking to recently visited questions... Especially when writing a meta question.