# Allow us to link to an image online

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, images

On the Android app you can upload an image but there isn't a way to link to an image online. For example if I wanted to add [image]

That image to a post I would either have to save it to my phone and then upload it or manually type in the short code for it.

Could the option be added to allow you to link to the image online?

Comment: If there's more demand for this I have zero issues with adding it.

Answer (score 8):

As of beta version 1.0.53 (coming out Monday, most likely) this is what you'll see when tapping the picture icon on the markdown toolbar:

[image: don't tell me what to do]

Comment: since I know people are going to ask, here's the image that linked to: http://i.imgur.com/Ylnigpl.jpg

Comment: Apparently the two people who upvoted your comment but not the answer are just here because they like cute pictures of cats. +1

Comment: I'm curious since I still can't see the update to 1.0.53. I'm already on 1.0.52, so I believe I have joined the beta (and I didn't do anything after that, including opt-out). Is it released already, or actually was planned to release on Monday?

Comment: @AndrewT. 1.0.53 isn't out yet because I forgot the build was broken :( it'll come tomorrow, I hope.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi was the update released after?

Comment: @Howli 1.0.53 is out to all beta users

Comment: Sweet thanks, I just checked and it's there.