# Does adding images from the web via the Android app not upload them to imgur?

Tags: bug, android-app, images

[I posted an answer from the Android app](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/92362/1) this morning and included an image from the web.

I used the upload image button, and selected upload from URL. However, the app did not upload the image to Imgur, just linked to the URL.

Is this standard behaviour?

I am using Version 1.0.89 running on Android 4.4.4. (and I used the button and upload from URL).

Comment: Did you use upload button? And did you use upload from device or URL?

Comment: @Pandya I used the button and upload from URL.

Comment: Correct, it just links to the image. Bug indeed, as it's expected to be consistent with the website.

Comment: FYI, source of confusion is [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246405/allow-us-to-link-to-an-image-online).

Comment: This is problematic with the recent ban on non-https images... which means that there will be an influx of empty image boxes.